# Get commit message and diff from Launchpad

Tags: python, launchpad, bazaar, bzrlib

Is it possible to get the commit message and the associated diff (changed file contents) of a project on Launchpad without cloning the repository? I tried using bzrlib as follows:

```
from bzrlib.branch import Branch
from bzrlib.plugin import load_plugins

load_plugins()
branch = Branch.open('lp:bzr')
revision_id = branch.last_revision()
revision = branch.repository.get_revision(revision_id)
# TODO: Get full commit message
tree = branch.repository.revision_tree(id)
# TODO: get only changes in this revision
```

Can launchpadlib be used for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use *launchpadlib* for that. The Launchpad API doesn't provide a mapping for branch contents or history.

You can get the diff for a specific set of revisions via *bzrlib* though. This is how Launchpad generates the diff contents for Merge Proposals. You don't need to clone a local copy of the branch to read it; *bzrlib* supports reading from remote branches. For example running `bzr diff -c -1 lp:bzr` will give you a diff of the last revision committed to lp:bzr.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly, but if there's no direct need to use *bzrlib* or *launchpadlib* for other reasons, you can simply run `bzr diff` with appropriate arguments, to get the diff you want.

Comment: Thanks for the `bzr` command, I actually didn't consider that.. but since I'm already in Python, I'd prefer to use `bzrlib` instead of shelling out to a `bzr` process. Also, it takes a lot of time to use `bzr` directly: `bzr diff -c -1 lp:bzr  0.49s user 0.04s system 0% cpu 1:06.26 total`.

Comment: Yes, the lp:bzr repository is pretty large (lots of history and files), and doing a command remotely rather than on a local copy is going to be slow. Doing the same work directly in Python, isn't going to be any faster. As bzr itself is written in Python, you'd literally be duplicating the code of the diff command in bzr. You can just call the diff command directly from within Python as well. You will need to create a script that initializes the commands and plug-ins of bzr though.